# Ubuntu Gnome login screen on ASUS GL552VW with closed lid

Tags: laptop, asus, login-screen, ubuntu-gnome, multiple-monitors

I've got an Asus GL552VW running Ubuntu Gnome 17.04. With a monitor connected to the HDMI port. The monitor is the primary screen and the laptop screen the secondary.

When i boot to the login screen with the lid closed i get the login screen on the laptop screen (even though i can tell by peaking the screen isn't even on) and nothing but the blank grey background on the monitor. If i open and close the lid then the login screen switches to the monitor.

I tried setting the screens to being mirrored to show the same thing on both screens. But after rebooting (with the lid closed) it still behaves the same way.

I got dual boot with Windows. And there it isn't an issue. So i doubt it's a hardware issue.

Comment: I have the same problem on my Razer Blade with Gnome Desktop on Ubuntu 17.04. If I reboot while my lid is closed, the laptop monitor will turn on, despite that the lid is closed. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:

- https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1444229
- https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/9512307

```
$ cat /sys/module/button/parameters/lid_init_state
$ sudo nano /etc/default/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="button.lid_init_state=method"
$ sudo update-grub
```