# Login with gdm on xorg stuck on background until I open laptop lid

Tags: 18.04, xorg, laptop, freeze, gdm

I have a dual monitor + laptop screen setup using a thunderbolt dock.

When I try to login to ubuntu with the laptop lid closed it works fine on wayland but with Xorg the screen freezes on the background image until I open the laptop lid, at which point the background will go away and I will get logged in as usual.

If I keep the laptop lid open it works just fine.

I have tried to follow the recommendation at [Ubuntu Gnome login screen on ASUS GL552VW with closed lid](https://askubuntu.com/questions/919817/ubuntu-gnome-login-screen-on-asus-gl552vw-with-closed-lid) but it does not help.